# How to combine the results of two queries?

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, select, procedure

I created a procedure that has two selects, I want to join the result of these two selects in one.

This is my procedure

```
CREATE PROCEDURE spConsultarVendas
    @nomeUsuario nvarchar(60), 
    @dataEmissao datetime, 
    @dataSaida datetime 
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT
        NF.ID, NF.NaturezaOperacao, NF.DataEmissao, NF.ValorTotal
    FROM   
        NotaFiscal AS NF
    INNER JOIN
        Venda AS V ON NF.ID_Venda = V.ID
    INNER JOIN
        Usuario AS U ON V.ID_UsuarioComissao1 = U.ID
    WHERE
        U.Descricao = @nomeUsuario 
        AND (NF.DataEmissao >= @dataEmissao AND NF.DataSaida <= @dataSaida)

    SELECT
        SUM(NF.ValorTotal) AS FinalValue
    FROM
        NotaFiscal AS NF
    INNER JOIN
        Venda AS V ON Nf.ID_Venda = V.ID
    INNER JOIN
        Usuario AS U ON V.ID_UsuarioComissao1 = U.ID
    WHERE
        U.Descricao = @nomeUsuario 
        AND (NF.DataEmissao >= @dataEmissao AND NF.DataSaida <= @dataSaida)
END
```

These are the results:

[image]

I want to combine these results into one.

Comment: What do you mean by combining them? How should the final result look?

Comment: Did you try anything to combine them? A window function maybe?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add the final result easily to each row of the first query:

```
SELECT NF.ID, NF.NaturezaOperacao, NF.DataEmissao, NF.ValorTotal,
       SUM(NF.ValorTotal) OVER () AS ValorFinal
FROM NotaFiscal NF INNER JOIN
     Venda V
     ON NF.ID_Venda = V.ID INNER JOIN
     Usuario U
     ON V.ID_UsuarioComissao1 = U.ID
WHERE U.Descricao = @nomeUsuario AND
      (NF.DataEmissao >= @dataEmissao AND NF.DataSaida <= @dataSaida)
```