# SUM values in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, group-by, sum

I have this query.

```
SELECT  NFI.ID_Produto, SUM(NFI.Quantidade) AS Quantidade, MIN(PS.Descricao) AS Nome, MIN(NFI.ValorUnitario) AS Valor,
    SUM(NFI.ValorTotal) AS ValorTotal
FROM NotaFiscal_Item NFI
INNER JOIN Produto_Servico PS ON NFI.ID_Produto = PS.ID
INNER JOIN NotaFiscal NF ON NFI.ID_NF = NF.ID
INNER JOIN Venda V ON NF.ID_Venda = V.ID
INNER JOIN Usuario U ON V.ID_UsuarioComissao1 = U.ID
WHERE U.Descricao = 'MANHA' AND (NF.DataEmissao >= '2019-04-05 12:00:00' AND NF.DataSaida <= '2019-04-05 23:59:59')
GROUP BY NFI.ID_Produto
ORDER BY ValorTotal DESC
```

And this is the result.

[image]

How do I sum the values of the column `ValorTotal` to show on the result?

Comment: Edit your question and show the results that you want.

Comment: How is this different from your previous question:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61019965/how-to-combine-the-results-of-two-queries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably, you want a window sum:

```
SELECT  
    NFI.ID_Produto, 
    SUM(NFI.Quantidade) AS Quantidade, 
    MIN(PS.Descricao) AS Nome, 
    MIN(NFI.ValorUnitario) AS Valor,
    SUM(NFI.ValorTotal) AS ValorTotal,
    SUM(SUM(NFI.ValorTotal)) OVER() AS ValorOverall
FROM ...
GROUP BY NFI.ID_Produto
ORDER BY ValorTotal DESC
```

This adds one more column to the resultset, with the grand total of `ValorTotal` (ie the sum of `ValorTotal` over all rows in the resultset).

Answer (score 0):

```
 SELECT SUM(T1.ValorTotal) AS SumOfValorTotal
 FROM
 (
    SELECT  NFI.ID_Produto, SUM(NFI.Quantidade) AS Quantidade, 
    MIN(PS.Descricao) AS 
    Nome, MIN(NFI.ValorUnitario) AS Valor,
    SUM(NFI.ValorTotal) AS ValorTotal
    FROM NotaFiscal_Item NFI
    INNER JOIN Produto_Servico PS ON NFI.ID_Produto = PS.ID
    INNER JOIN NotaFiscal NF ON NFI.ID_NF = NF.ID
    INNER JOIN Venda V ON NF.ID_Venda = V.ID
    INNER JOIN Usuario U ON V.ID_UsuarioComissao1 = U.ID
    WHERE U.Descricao = 'MANHA' AND (NF.DataEmissao >= '2019-04-05 12:00:00' AND 
    NF.DataSaida <= '2019-04-05 23:59:59')
    GROUP BY NFI.ID_Produto
  )  AS T1
```